# How to manage events on two different elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, events

I created [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-chaplygin-rlire?file=/src/App.js) that reproduce my problem.

Basically I have a container div composed by texts and an "icon" (the `i` button). What I need is trigger two different events when user click on the `i` and when user click inside the container (avoiding the `i`). The problem is that the `i` div is inside the container so I don't know how to split the two events.

In my code, when I click on card I get:

```js
card
```

that is right, when I click on 'i' I get:

```js
info!
card
```

but it should be only

```js
info!
```

How can I fix? I'm open change the html structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behaviour of javascript events. In this 3 phase occur when an event is fired

1. Capturing phase (JS goes from window, document, followed by every element until it reaches the event target)
2. Target phase (It is at the target element that fired the event)
3. Bubbling phase (JS goes through every HTML element, starting from the target, back to window)

You need to `stopPropagation` so that the event of `container` won't execute.[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-water-ijxez?file=/src/App.js)

[Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```
  function clickHandler( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log( e.target );
  }
```

and on the JSX

```
  return (
    <div className="container" onClick={clickHandler}>
      <div className="first-line">
        <div className="header">
          <div className="title">title</div>
          <div className="circle" onClick={clickHandler}>
            i
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="subtitle">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte adipiscing elit
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="second-line">Link to section</div>
    </div>
  );
```